# Lock functions don't work for my account since update to 22.04

Tags: gnome, suspend, lock-screen, 22.04

Since the upgrade to 22.04, my user account no longer appears to have an option to lock the computer:

- There's no "lock" option in the panel menu
- Windows-L doesn't work
- It doesn't lock when the laptop lid is closed (the screen does go off); and
- It doesn't lock when the screen goes off on time-out.

The frustrating thing (apart from the fact my kids have spotted it and my Youtube history is now filling up with cartoons!) is that this is only a problem on my (administrator) account.

I've tried:

- changing Settings under Privacy>Screen (the settings were the same for the other users anyway);
- [Uncommenting lines in /etc/systemd][1];
- [running gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled true][2]; and
- Shouting at it.

Is there anythign else anyone would suggest?

Many thanks,

G
[1]: https://fostips.com/lid-close-action-ubuntu-21-04-laptop/
[2]: https://linuxhint.com/disable-screen-lock-ubuntu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was annoyed by the same issue for a while and also was unable to find a solution. Eventually I searched gnome settings in terminal and one of them caught my attention. After setting this to `false`

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false
```

not only **Lock** option appeared in the top bar menu

[image]

but also <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> shortcut started working!

Comment: Fantastic.  That solved it.  Thank you very much.